# Creating CGImage via byte array sometimes results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, core-image, cgimage

I'm trying to create a CGImage from a byte array, with something similar to this example function that generates a red square on a black field:

```
var bgrArray: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 480*480*4)
for i in 50..<250 {
    for j in 50..<250 {
        bgrArray[(i*480+j)*4] = 255
        bgrArray[(i*480+j)*4+1] = 0
        bgrArray[(i*480+j)*4+2] = 0
        bgrArray[(i*480+j)*4+3] = 0
    }
}

let releaseMaskImagePixelData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
    return
}

let provider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: bgrArray, size: bgrArray.count, releaseData: releaseMaskImagePixelData)!
let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitsPerComponent = 8;
let bitsPerPixel = 32;
let bytesPerRow = 4 * 480;

let bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = [.byteOrder32Big, CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)]
let img = CGImage(width: 480, height: 480, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorspace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, provider: provider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false, intent: .defaultIntent)
let uiimage = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
return CIImage(image: uiimage)!
```

I have this exact bit of code copied into two different projects, in one project it always succeeds and in the other the line `let img = CGImage(width: 480, height: 480, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorspace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, provider: provider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false, intent: .defaultIntent)` always fails with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The fact that it succeeds in one project and fails in another confuses me, is this bit of code able to be impacted by other things going on in an app?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is due to optimization, seems like the exception occurs when optimization is turned on.

Comment: What "optimization" are we talking about? Can you make this answer a bit more useful? Thanks!

Comment: Yes this issue occurred when I built with -Os, but did not occur when built with -O0

Comment: Aha, I see, thanks. That's still very odd.